# SceneKit - Position 3D model correctly on Screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, scenekit

Hi I've been using a 3D model .dae object taken from example i.e. for Mac

[Scene Kit Example](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SceneKitDocumentViewer/Listings/SceneKitDocumentViewer_ASCView_m.html)

I copied the sample to `iOS` default code (Ship example) But not able to adjust the camera

```
SCNNode *cameraNode = [SCNNode node];
cameraNode.camera = [SCNCamera camera];
[scene.rootNode addChildNode:cameraNode];

// place the camera
cameraNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 100);
```

I have changed the z axis from 100-1000 but not luck so far. How can I adjust this character right on to the screen as it is in mac example code

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that "cameraNode" is the only camera in the scene and the current active camera? Did you try to force it to be the active camera with:

```
scnView.pointOfView = cameraNode;
```

Comment: There i only one active camera. Tried this code too but no effect

Comment: Does your DAE file contains animations that apply on the camera?

Comment: No. i am just trying to create a 3d model for learning. most simple code the apple provides when we create a default scenekit app.